# перемещение drag and drop и изменение размеров

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop, resize

Не могу сделать так что бы drag and drop срабатовало менялся размер по отдельности все работает а вместе только drag and drop срабатывает

[вот где меняется размер http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rzu/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rzu/8/),

[а вот все вместе, но срабатывает только drag and drop http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rzu/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rzu/9/)

```js
  var delta_w = 0; // Изменение по ширине
  var delta_h = 0; // Изменение по высоте
  /* После загрузки страницы */

    /* Определяем браузер */

   
    block_r = document.getElementById("square-rect"); // Получаем блок для изменения размеров

    document.onmouseup = clearXY; // Ставим обработку на отпускание кнопки мыши
    block_r.onmousedown = saveWH; // Ставим обработку на нажатие кнопки мыши

  /* Функция для получения текущих координат курсора мыши */
  function getXY(obj_event) {
    if (obj_event) {
      x = obj_event.pageX;
      y = obj_event.pageY;
    }
    else {
      x = window.event.clientX;
      y = window.event.clientY;
      if (ie) {
        y -= 2;
        x -= 2;
      }
    }
    return new Array(x, y);
  }
  function saveWH(obj_event) {
    var point = getXY(obj_event);
    w_block = ball.clientWidth; // Текущая ширина блока
    h_block = ball.clientHeight; // Текущая высота блока
    delta_w = w_block - point[0]; // Измеряем текущую разницу между шириной и x-координатой мыши
    delta_h = h_block - point[1]; // Измеряем текущую разницу между высотой и y-координатой мыши
    /* Ставим обработку движения мыши для разных браузеров */
    document.onmousemove = resizeBlock;
     document.addEventListener("onmousemove", resizeBlock, false);
    return false; // Отключаем стандартную обработку нажатия мыши
  }
  /* Функция для измерения ширины окна */
  function clientWidth() {
    return image.width;
  }
  /* Функция для измерения высоты окна */
  function clientHeight() {
    return image.height;
  }
  /* При отпускании кнопки мыши отключаем обработку движения курсора мыши */
  function clearXY() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
  function resizeBlock(obj_event) {
    var point = getXY(obj_event);
    new_w = delta_w + point[0]; // Изменяем новое приращение по ширине
    new_h = delta_h + point[1]; // Изменяем новое приращение по высоте
    ball.style.width = new_w + "px"; // Устанавливаем новую ширину блока
    ball.style.height = new_h + "px"; // Устанавливаем новую высоту блока
    /* Если блок выходит за пределы экрана, то устанавливаем максимальные значения для ширины и высоты */
    if (ball.offsetLeft + ball.clientWidth > clientWidth()) 
      ball.style.width = (clientWidth() - ball.offsetLeft)  + "px";
    if (ball.offsetTop + ball.clientHeight > clientHeight())
      ball.style.height = (clientHeight() - ball.offsetTop) + "px";
  }            
                

Element.prototype.makeDraggable=function(){
  var o=this


  o.onmousedown=function(e){
    var offsetX=e.pageX-parseInt(o.style.left)
    var offsetY=e.pageY-parseInt(o.style.top)



    document.onmousemove=function(e) {
      o.style.left=Math.max(Math.min(e.pageX-offsetX,o.parentNode.clientWidth-o.clientWidth),0)+'px'
      o.style.top=Math.max(Math.min(e.pageY-offsetY,o.parentNode.clientHeight-o.clientHeight),0)+'px'
    

    var Xtop=parseInt(o.style.top);
    var Xleft=parseInt(o.style.left);



    }
    document.onmouseup = function(e) {
      document.onmousemove=o.onmouseup=null
    }
  }
  o.ondragstart = function(){return 0}
}
ball.makeDraggable()
```

```css
#parent{
position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:13px;

  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  z-index: 100;
  border:1px solid;
}
#ball{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
   border:1px solid;

}
#square-rect {
    background-color: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="ball" style="left:10px;top:10px;" class="rect-war">
<span id="square-rect"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: при перетаскивании ты затираешь обработчик move, и при окончании перетаскивания ты его обнуляешь, поэтому resize и не работает.

Comment: что за переменные в условии `if (op || ff)`? они нигде не объявлены

Comment: @Grundy я их убрал но все также помогите плиз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема во всплытии события `mousedown`. Так как элемент с id `square-rect` расположен внутри элемента с id `ball` событие `mousedown` для него будет всплывать и на самом деле будут вызваны оба обработчика и для `square-rect` и для `ball`, причем в обработчике для `ball` переопределяется обработчик `mousemove` для документа. Поэтому видно только движение элемента, а не изменение размера.

Для решения достаточно остановить всплытие в обработчике mousedown элемента `square-rect` с помощью функции [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
var delta_w = 0; // Изменение по ширине
var delta_h = 0; // Изменение по высоте
/* После загрузки страницы */

/* Определяем браузер */


block_r = document.getElementById("square-rect"); // Получаем блок для изменения размеров

document.onmouseup = clearXY; // Ставим обработку на отпускание кнопки мыши
block_r.onmousedown = saveWH; // Ставим обработку на нажатие кнопки мыши

/* Функция для получения текущих координат курсора мыши */
function getXY(obj_event) {
  if (obj_event) {
    x = obj_event.pageX;
    y = obj_event.pageY;
  } else {
    x = window.event.clientX;
    y = window.event.clientY;
    if (ie) {
      y -= 2;
      x -= 2;
    }
  }
  return new Array(x, y);
}

function saveWH(obj_event) {
  obj_event.stopPropagation();
  var point = getXY(obj_event);
  w_block = ball.clientWidth; // Текущая ширина блока
  h_block = ball.clientHeight; // Текущая высота блока
  delta_w = w_block - point[0]; // Измеряем текущую разницу между шириной и x-координатой мыши
  delta_h = h_block - point[1]; // Измеряем текущую разницу между высотой и y-координатой мыши
  /* Ставим обработку движения мыши для разных браузеров */
  document.onmousemove = resizeBlock;
  document.addEventListener("onmousemove", resizeBlock, false);
  return false; // Отключаем стандартную обработку нажатия мыши
}
/* Функция для измерения ширины окна */
function clientWidth() {
  return image.width;
}
/* Функция для измерения высоты окна */
function clientHeight() {
  return image.height;
}
/* При отпускании кнопки мыши отключаем обработку движения курсора мыши */
function clearXY() {
  document.onmousemove = null;
}

function resizeBlock(obj_event) {
  var point = getXY(obj_event);
  new_w = delta_w + point[0]; // Изменяем новое приращение по ширине
  new_h = delta_h + point[1]; // Изменяем новое приращение по высоте
  ball.style.width = new_w + "px"; // Устанавливаем новую ширину блока
  ball.style.height = new_h + "px"; // Устанавливаем новую высоту блока
  /* Если блок выходит за пределы экрана, то устанавливаем максимальные значения для ширины и высоты */
  if (ball.offsetLeft + ball.clientWidth > clientWidth())
    ball.style.width = (clientWidth() - ball.offsetLeft) + "px";
  if (ball.offsetTop + ball.clientHeight > clientHeight())
    ball.style.height = (clientHeight() - ball.offsetTop) + "px";
}


Element.prototype.makeDraggable = function() {
  var o = this


  o.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var offsetX = e.pageX - parseInt(o.style.left)
    var offsetY = e.pageY - parseInt(o.style.top)



    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
      o.style.left = Math.max(Math.min(e.pageX - offsetX, o.parentNode.clientWidth - o.clientWidth), 0) + 'px'
      o.style.top = Math.max(Math.min(e.pageY - offsetY, o.parentNode.clientHeight - o.clientHeight), 0) + 'px'


      var Xtop = parseInt(o.style.top);
      var Xleft = parseInt(o.style.left);



    }
    document.onmouseup = function(e) {
      document.onmousemove = o.onmouseup = null
    }
  }
  o.ondragstart = function() {
    return 0
  }
}
ball.makeDraggable()
```

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 13px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#ball {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#square-rect {
  background-color: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="ball" style="left:10px;top:10px;" class="rect-war">
    <span id="square-rect"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```